# Having trouble hiding fields in ASP.NET core 2.0 -how is this properly done without commenting out?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have an application where I want to hide some text fields and dropdowns that have some default values give because it is for end users where what fields they enter are restricted and they dont need to see for create and edit.

When they are visible everything works fine.

Is it possible to make them hidden, and yet still have the default values so that it saves successfully. Under standard .net MVC, i could do this no problem even making fields hidden, but not under .net core . Traditional MVC had  code like:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority, "Priority", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Priority, "Priority")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("Priority", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
            @Html.DropDownList("Priority", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "hidden" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

.net core scaffolds using syntax like

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Priority" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Priority" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Priority"></select>
        </div>
```

Justing commenting out fields causes all sorts of problems and doest work. What is appropriate syntax for hiding text fields and dropdownlists? Thanks

Comment: You can still use the `@Html.` helper class in your razor views.  The scaffolder may output tag helpers but use is optional.  As for hiding form elements based on permissions then use an `@if...else` block and render the input element if they have permission, otherwise render a hidden input element with the value set if they don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to apply a class `hidden` to it, then you can just include it in the tag’s `class` attribute:

```
<select asp-for="Priority" class="hidden" asp-items="ViewBag.Priority"></select>
```

Remember that tag helpers are just normal HTML elements with a little magic on top, so usually you can treat them like normal HTML tags, which also means that you can add all the normal HTML attributes like you would normally do.

If you actually want to generate a hidden field (instead of some input that has a `hidden` class), you can just render an `input` element of type `hidden`:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="model.Priority" />
```

Comment: Thanks- the class= hidden achieved what i was trying to do!